# Plotting vertical line on matplotlib stacked area graph

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I trying to plot a stacked area graph using matplotlib with vertical line(s) on top. My MWE is:

```
  import numpy as np
  import pandas as pd
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  # my data
  df = pd.DataFrame(data={'date': pd.date_range(start='2020-09-01', freq='D', periods=100),
                          'x1': np.random.randint(80,200,size=100),
                          'x2': np.random.randint(50,90,size=100),
                          'x3': np.random.randint(50,100,size=100),
                         })
  df = df.set_index('date')

  df0 = df.query("index == 20201026")  # points of interest

  fig = plt.figure()
  ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
  df.plot(ax=ax, kind='area')
  ax.vlines(df0.index, ymin=0, ymax=1000, color='k', lw=1)
  # ax.vlines(pd.concat([df0,df0], axis=0).index, ymin=0, ymax=1000, color='k', lw=1, ls='--')
  ax.set_ylim((0,400))
  ax.legend(loc='lower right')
  plt.show()
```

The area graph is plotted using `df` and any point(s) of interest are in `df0`. If there is just **one point** in `df0`, when I plot using `vlines` I get an error

`TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

But if I use `pd.concat([df0,df0], axis=0)`, there's no problem with `vlines`. Why does this happen? I can't find anything in the docs that say `vlines` must accept more than one vertical line.

Comment: Matplotlib and pandas don't always play nicely together when it comes to dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib doesn't know how to deal with `pd.Index`. Use `tolist` to solve the problem:

```
ax.vlines(df0.index.tolist(), ymin=0, ymax=1000, color='k', lw=1)
#             HERE ---^
```

Solution proposed by @BigBen:

```
#                        HERE ---v
df.plot(ax=ax, kind='area', x_compat=True)
ax.vlines(df0.index, ymin=0, ymax=1000, color='k', lw=1)
```

[image]

Comment: `x_compat=True` to the original `plot` call also works, but then you lose the x-axis formatting...

Comment: @BigBen. Thanks for your solution. I don't find anything about `x_compat` on documentation. Do you have a link for this parameter?

Comment: It's explained for example [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.10.0/visualization.html) (older version, but seems to still be applicable).